# How to handle math operations for custom types whose operations may error (ex. Ok(1) + Ok(2))

Tags: rust

## Context

I'm working on implementing field operations in Rust as a way to earn more about cryptography and Rust. I have a FieldElement type on which I've implemented basic traits from `std::ops`.

```rust
use anyhow::{anyhow, Result};
use std::ops::{Sub, Add, Mul, Div};
use num_traits::PrimInt;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct FieldElement {
    num: i128,
    prime: i128
}

impl FieldElement {
    pub fn new(num: i128, prime: i128) -> Result<Self> {
        if prime <= 0 {
            return Err(anyhow!("prime must be non-negative: ({},{})", num, prime));
        }
        if num >= prime {
            return Err(anyhow!("num must be less than prime: ({},{})", num, prime));
        }
        Ok(Self {
            num,
            prime
        })
    }

    pub fn pow(&self, exp: i128) -> Result<Self> {
        ...
    }

    fn same_field(a: &FieldElement, b: &FieldElement) -> bool {
        a.prime == b.prime
    }
}

impl Add for FieldElement {
    type Output = Result<FieldElement>;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Result<Self> {
        ...
    }
}

impl Sub for FieldElement {
    type Output = Result<FieldElement>;

    fn sub(self, other: Self) -> Result<Self> {
        ...
    }
}

impl Mul for FieldElement {
    type Output = Result<FieldElement>;

    fn mul(self, other: Self) -> Result<Self> {
        ...
    }
}

// Used for Scalar multiplication
impl <T: PrimInt> Mul<T> for FieldElement {
    type Output = FieldElement;

    fn mul(self, rhs: T) -> Self {
        ...
    }
}

impl Div for FieldElement {
    type Output = Result<FieldElement>;

    fn div(self, other: Self) -> Result<Self> {
        ...
    }
}
```

This felt right when writing the types but now mathematical operations feel very rigid because each operation requires manual unpacking. See the example below, where the matched `x` and `y` variables have type `FieldElement`:

```rust
...
impl CurvePoint {
    pub fn new(point: Option<Point>, a: FieldElement, b: FieldElement) -> Result<Self> {
        if let Some(Point {x, y}) = point {
            let rhs = ((x.pow(3)? + (a * x)?)? + b)?;
            if y.pow(2)? != rhs {
                return Err(anyhow!("(x,y) must be on the curve x^3 + ax + b"));
            }
        }
        Ok(Self { point, a, b })
    }
}
```

While this is correct, the parentheses and question marks add noise to the business logic.

## Question

Is there a better practice here? I'd like to avoid panic, but maybe that's appropriate in this scenario. I could also implement methods that handle the `Err` checks, but I'm trying to stick to operator overloading.

## Attempts

### Try 1: Implementing for Result

My first attempt was to implement the operation traits for `Result<FieldElement>`. I'm new to Rust, so this seemed reasonable. However, I received a compiler error stating `'Result' is not defined in the current create`. I did some reading on this and seems expected.

### Try 2: Implementing Op<Result> for FieldElement

I had run into a similar error message in (1) before when I was trying to implement scalar multiplication. I tried `impl Mul<Result<FieldElement>> for FieldElement` but received a compiler error stating there were two conflicting implementations of `Mul` for `FieldElement`. I did some reading here too and found this is expected so that a trait cannot be implemented twice (though this is exactly what I was hoping to do). Here are the conflicting traits:

```rust
impl <T: PrimInt> Mul<T> for FieldElement { ... }
impl Mul<Result<FieldElement>> for FieldElement { ... }
```

The `PrimInt` trait bound comes from `num_traits`. It's part of my scalar multiplication implementation (ex. 3 * FieldElement{1, 13}), which I need to support.

### Try 3: Macros?

I'm out of my depth at this point, so I started looking around. I found the [auto_ops](https://github.com/carbotaniuman/auto_ops) library, but that seems to focus on variants of operations that come up with ownership. While this doesn't solve my problem, I'm thinking I may want to take a similar approach.

### Try 4: Try 2 with adjusted Scalar Multiplication

Since I know the type of integer I'm working with (`i128`), I can follow the approach described in two if I adjust the scalar multiplication trait:

```rust
impl Mul for FieldElement {
    type Output = Result<FieldElement>;

    fn mul(self, other: Self) -> Result<Self> {
        ...
    }
}

impl Mul<Result<FieldElement>> for FieldElement {
    type Output = Result<FieldElement>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Result<FieldElement>) -> Self::Output {
        if let Ok(el) = rhs {
            el * self
        } else {
            rhs
        }
    }
}
impl Mul<FieldElement> for i128 {
    type Output = FieldElement;

    fn mul(self, rhs: FieldElement) -> Self::Output {
        ...
    }
}
```

Taking that approach with the other operations, I can write remove some of the syntax, but I think the readability is worse due to the non-standard form. It also doesn't completely address my problem.

```rust
// Before
((x.pow(3)? + (a * x)?)? + b)?;

// After
(b + a*x)? + x.pow(3);

// Ideal
let foo: Result<FieldElement> = x.pow(3) + a*x + b
```

Comment: To me, mathematical operations are not really expected to fail, in the sense that the API is designed without failure in mind. In this particular case, it looks like you are trying to encode elements of a finite field `F_p`, and multiplication is always between such elements is always well-defined.

Comment: Fair enough. Overflows are possible and operations are not defined between two elements not from the same field (ex. a in F_3 + b in F_5). Since this isn't seeing production, I'm comfortable assuming things will work. That said, I figured I'd ask to see if there's a way I can sharpen my Rust skills.

Answer (score 0):

As jthulhu mentioned in the comments, it's not usually expected that mathematical operations in a finite field fail.  Since it's the case that you have an easy way to determine if two items are in the same finite field, it's safe to assume that a user who wants to verify that fact (and thus, whether the operation will succeed) can call that method.

What I would do here is simply panic if the two fields are not the same.  It's a programmer error and there's a simple way to check.  In addition, this mirrors other operations in Rust such as indexing, which panic in the same way, while providing easy ways to determine if they would in fact succeed if the caller is unsure.

Comment: As an addendum, to provide non-panicking alternatives, they could add `.checked_*` methods like in the standard library, which could return `Option` (or `Result` if there are multiple types of failure).